# Run out of ram C++

Tags: c++, ram

I´m working with a 4D matrix (using STL vectors). Usually, the dimensions are different.For example, I´m reading a matrix whose dimensions are 192x256x128x96, and the following code complete with 0´s to the bigger dimension (256 in this case).

```
while(matriz.size() < width)   //width es el tamaño de N
{
    vector<vector<vector<short>>> aux;
    matriz.push_back(aux);
}

for(auto i = 0; i < matriz.size(); i++)
{
    while(matriz[i].size() < width)
    {
        vector<vector<short>> aux;
        matriz[i].push_back(aux);
    }
}


for(auto i = 0; i < matriz.size(); i++)
    for(auto j = 0; j < matriz[i].size(); j++)
        while(matriz[i][j].size() < width)
        {
            vector<short> aux;
            matriz[i][j].push_back(aux);
        }   
            


for(auto i = 0; i < matriz.size(); i++) 
    for(auto j = 0; j < matriz[i].size(); j++)
        for(auto k = 0; k < matriz[i][j].size(); k++)  
            while(matriz[i][j][k].size() < width)  
            {
                matriz[i][j][k].push_back(0);
            }
```

That code works with little-medium size 4D matrix, I´ve been tried with 200x200x200x200 and it really works, but I need to use it with a 256x256x256x256 matrix and when I run it my computer doesn´t respond.

I´m not sure if it is a RAM issue. My computer has 12GB RAM, and if I'm not mistaken, the size of the matrix is 8GB.

Any idea how to fix this ?

**edit**

If I let the program works, a time later it is killed
[image: The program is killed]

The memory usage with a 200x200x200x200 matrix is 56.7%

[image: memory usage]

Comment: What operating system? What version? What bit-size? These are all important questions. For example: Windows 10 Home 64-bit has a process memory limit of 128 GB, way above your requirements. However, *all* Windows 10 32-bit versions have a process memory limit of 4 GB, half the size of your largest requirement.

Comment: @Casey given that he has 12GB of RAM I doubt he still runs 32-bit OS.

Comment: @MichałKaczorowski Just covering all the bases.

Comment: your program has `O(n^4)` time complexity. This means that the time to run your program just explodes past a certain `n`. This is most likely what happens. Your program runs, but it takes a vey very long time to finish.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bits

Comment: But it doesnt respond, i mean i cant move the mouse

Comment: @Miguel Posadas can you provide more details? What does it mean your PC doesn't respond? How long do you wait? Do you also monitor your memory usage? You are correct that it will allocate 8GB of memory for that matrix, **but** since you don't call reserve it will also do **a lot** of vector resizing.

Comment: Sidenote: Instead of the repeated `push_back` you could intialize it in one line: `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short>>>> d(width, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short>>>(width, std::vector<std::vector<short>>(width, std::vector<short>(width))));`. One very ugly line to be fair.

Comment: @MichałKaczorowski This. Flatten the vector from 3 nested vectors into a single vector and `vector::reserve(16777216)` the elements beforehand.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on (`-O3`)?

Comment: I have edited the post with some new information

Comment: I dont use any optimization, Would I use it ?

Comment: @MiguelPosadas you said it works with a 200x200x200x200 matrix, could you run it again with that matrix and post the memory usage ? And your normal memory usage, too.

Comment: Well running a release version (optimized) is usually many times faster. Also try reserving vector space before filling them, this will avoid costly re-allocation. See `vector::reserve`. Finally you don't need to `push_back` empty sub-vectors, you can just `resize()` the vector which will create the needed elements automatically (thus also saving time and memory).

Comment: i have just post the memory usage with a 200x200x200x200 matrix

Comment: with  optimizations on (-O3) i have the same issues @rustyx, If i resize the structure it is filled with 0's ?

Comment: The last thing that @rustyx said works, thank you all so much, if u marked as response i could close the question :)

Comment: @MiguelPosadas well, 200 * 200 * 200 * 200 shorts == 3,200,000,000 bytes, but in reality 8GB of ram are used, so you would need about 11 GB of RAM for your 256 matrix. The ram then fills up to almost 100%, and that means, that your PC will freeze forever. For the 256 matrix, you will need at least 13 or 14 GB RAM, else it __will__freeze, unless you do something to optimize your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips (from the comments):

1. Run an optimized build (`-O3`), this should speed up processing.
2. Instead of `push_back()` of an empty `vector` in a loop, use [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). This will prevent costly reallocation.

   So for example, replace

   ```
    while(matriz.size() < width)   //width es el tamaño de N
    {
        vector<vector<vector<short>>> aux;
        matriz.push_back(aux);
    }
   ```

   With

   ```
    matriz.resize(width);
   ```

   If you do still need to use `push_back()` in a loop, at least [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the capacity beforehand. This can again prevent costly reallocations. Reallocating a vector can briefly double the amount of memory that it would normally use.
3. Use tools like `top` to watch memory and swap usage on the machine in real time. If you notice swap space used increasing, that means the machine is running out of memory.

Answer (score 5):

Let's see if I have this right.

You are producing:

- 1 vector that holds:
- 256 vectors that each hold
- 256 vectors that each hold (65,536 in total)
- 256 vectors that each hold (16,777,216 in total)
- 256 shorts (4,294,967,296 in total, or 8,589,934,592 Bytes as you indicated)

I don't know the entire size of each vector itself, but probably well under 1k, so you're using less than 10 gig of memory.

However, that's a LOT going on. Is it really hanging, or is it just taking a very, very long time.

Some debug output periodically would help answer that.

Comment: I have edited the original post with the output, sorry I should post it at begining